# Vuejs computed value is readonly

Tags: vuejs3

I'm doing props with vuejs, but there is no error, it works properly, but there is the error I mentioned below in the console, what kind of error am I making in the subcomponent?
I wonder if I have a mistake on the computed side, I couldn't figure it out.

`Write operation failed: computed value is readonly`

App.vue

```
<template>
<multiple-select :options="languageOptions" v-model="selectedLanguage"/>
</template>
<script setup>
const selectedLanguage = ref([])
const languageOptions = ref([
        {name: 'Turkish', language: 'tr'},
        {name: 'English', language: 'en'},
        {name: 'Arabic', language: 'ar'},
])
</script>
```

```
<template>
    <div>
        <vue-multiselect
            v-model="value"
            :options="options"
            :multiple="true"
            @update:model-value="inputChanged"
            placeholder="Dil Seçin"
            label="name"
            track-by="name"
            :searchable="false"
            select-label="Seç"
            selected-label="Seçili"
            deselect-label="Seçimi Kaldır"
            :allow-empty="false">
            </vue-multiselect>
        </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import VueMultiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
import 'vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.css'
import {defineEmits, computed} from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
        modelValue: Array,
        options: Array
});
let emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);
const value = computed(() => {
        return props.modelValue
})

function inputChanged(e) {
        emit('update:modelValue', e)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define the computed with a getter and setter and I think this will solve your problem:

```
const value = computed({
    get: () => props.modelValue,
    set: (val) => emit('update:modelValue', val)
});
function inputChanged(e) {
    value = e
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. but the error exists `Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable`  `inputChanged` there is an error here